# TypeScript: Create a new type from a nested object values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a new type from nested object value but if the key is not present
on any of the nested levels, it is failing, Where I'm going wrong?

```
const events = [
  { name: 'foo' },
  { name: 'bar' },
  { value: 'baz' }
] as const;


type Events = typeof events;

type AllValuesOf<T> = T extends any ? T[keyof T] : never;

// Error: Property 'name' does not exist on the type 
type Name = AllValuesOf<Events>['name'] // ideally I want this to be 'foo' | 'bar'
```

Expected

```
type Name = "foo" | "bar"
```

[Ts Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgNzmKEYF4YG0BQMYDeMYAhgLZwBcMA5AGYgg0wC+ANHoceVbQEYkATs3aciCEgBsArrxoCAXiJwBdGCTShIUANw59UAJ4AHODACiSFGkxHTIOvCuo9OO2YCCkyQDUpsiAB5OgAeABUAPgwYMPgADyhkABM0EjBDGAB+GKwAazhDBxi1ajBEOEFXdxgAOR5or19-OCDQy2RUCKwaUgoaFRwgA)

Comment: What do you want `AllValuesOf<Events>` to look like?  `{name: "foo" | "bar"; value: "baz"}` or something?

Comment: Nope, `name` is optional so if it is present I need those as types,
`type Name = "foo" | "bar"` @jcalz

Comment:  You want `type Name = AllValuesOf<Events>["name"]` to be `"foo | "bar"`, so what do you want `AllValuesOf<Events>` to look like?  `{name: "foo" | "bar"; value: "baz"}`?  If not, what specifically do you want it to look like?  ... I have [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7QjqW) which seems to be what you want, but your previous reply gives me pause.  At least one of us is confused here.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @jcalz My bad, Yes `AllValues<Events>` should look like `name: "foo" | "bar"; value: "baz"}`

Comment: @jcalz Thank you so much that is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @jcalz If you can post it as an answer I will be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: @jcalz I hope it is not much, but if possible could you also show me how to achieve this if events were an `object` of `objects` instead of an `array` of `objects`?

Comment: change `Events[number]` to `Obj[keyof Obj]`; hopefully we won't expand the question or answer scope to deal with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'd like to take `Events` and produce a type of the following form, programmatically:

```
type AllEvents = {
    name: "foo" | "bar";
    value: "baz";
}
```

That way you could [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `"name"` to get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"foo" | "bar"`, or index into it with `"value"` to get `"baz"`.

If we start with a union `T` of object types (expected to be `Events[number]`, the union of elements of `events`), then we first need to find the full set of its keys.  We can do this by [distributing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the [`keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) over unions in `T`:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
```

Then we can `Combine` them into a single object type.  For each key `K` in `AllKeys<T>`, we filter the `T` union for just those members with key `K`, and grab the value type at that key.  This is another job for distributive conditional types, also using [the `infer` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to do the "grabbing":

```
type Combine<T> = 
  { [K in AllKeys<T>]: T extends Record<K, infer V> ? V : never };
```

Put that together and we get the desired `AllEvents` type:

```
type AllEvents = Combine<Events[number]>;
/* type AllEvents = {
    name: "foo" | "bar";
    value: "baz";
} */
```

And you can index into it as desired:

```
type Name = AllEvents['name'];
//type Name = "foo" | "bar"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgNzmKEYF4YG0BQMYDeMYAhgLZwBcMA5AGYgg0wC+ANHoceVbQEYkATs3aciCEgBsArrxoCAXiJwBdGCTShIUANw4cUAJ4AHODACiSFGkxHTIOvCuo9dswEFJkgNJxDEAB4AFQA+DBgg+AAPKGQAEzRpMABrMBAAdzAYAH4YZL8HCJhqMEQ4QT0DEzMAYRAyPgBLUuCwzCIsbxhmmE8fP0DQlWpIuBj4tAAlOFBBOIDvNm6wOnKYADUw3PXi4jLBVkq3Xq9LZFRwuobmuACz6ywwaQbylRC9AHoAKhhjvvuLu1OPhSBRqAAiBggcEwAA+MHBAkE4L0+HwEhkvERJAUKJwLBgXw++mOADkeOF-s4IFgaKC4DQVJ8PmSKZhIYwYfDscicEA)